Are diagnostic tests and clinical (risk) prediction models in medicine essentially the same thing?
In medicine, are diagnostic tests (e.g. covid test, HIV test, ...) and risk prediction models essentially the same thing? If not, in which aspects do they differ (from statistical point of view)? Because both seems to take some individual level data and output some results regarding some disease. However, prediction models are often based on logistic regression/Bayesian statistics, while diagnostic tests are not.
